# Resetting a server with RasPi's GPIO

Tags: gpio, reset

I have a server (standard ATX motherboard) that tends to lock up, and I'd like to reset it using the Raspi.  I know the motherboard has a reset switch/jumper, but I don't know what voltage it outputs to detect when it's closed.  Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?  It seems like GPIO 18 could pull the line high and perform the reset, but I don't want to fry a pin or the board if I can help it.

Thanks!

Comment: you can safely use a solid state relay to do that. the connect the reset button into the inputs and the trigger to the Pi. That way there is no risk of frying the motherboard and you wont have the floating voltage problem either that could reset the motherboard when you don't expect it to. But i agree with Lenik. Find the cause of the hanging first.

Answer (score 1):

reset jumper usually connects a pulled-up (or pulled-down) pin to the ground (or power), you may use voltmeter to find out by measuring the voltage difference between pins and then between pins with a jumper attached and the ground.

still, I would advise against doing whatever you're planning to do, because if the motherboard locks up, it's better to find the reason (bad memory? broken PCB?) and either fix it or throw away. your files are more important than however much the broken parts might cost.

on the other hand, I'd use Raspi as a headless file/print server, it has hardware watchdog, that pulls the reset when something wrong happens. so,maybe it's time to replace your ITX with a Raspberry PI? =)